were there any other attempts to produce Amrita after the original Samudramanthana?
The original Samudramanthana ended unfairly for the Asuras.  They were partially compensated with the Mrta-Sanjivani mantra given by Siva to Shukracharya.
Did the Asuras or humans or other species try to achieve immortality (=a very long life) by similar methods or through alchemy?

Yes, if it is like a Yagna the procedure  must have been repeated many times again as the goal of attaining immortality is attractive.
